# Three.js Collisions GLTF

Tags: javascript, three.js, game-development

I have a GLTF scene/level that is impoted in my game and I want to block player from going inside  walls.
The level : https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/backrooms-level-0-3a43c43be8864c09aa0dff37c0b82001

and my loader code:

```
loader.load(
// resource URL
"../../models/scene.gltf",
// called when the resource is loaded
function (gltf) {
  scene.add(gltf.scene);
  level = gltf.scene;
  gltf.animations; // Array<THREE.AnimationClip>
  gltf.scene; // THREE.Group
  gltf.scenes; // Array<THREE.Group>
  gltf.cameras; // Array<THREE.Camera>
  gltf.asset; // Object
},
// called while loading is progressing
function (xhr) {
  console.log((xhr.loaded / xhr.total) * 100 + "% loaded");
},
// called when loading has errors
function (error) {
  console.error(error);
}
return { level };
```

);

Comment: I think you'll need to narrow down the question, this is probably too broad for Stack Overflow. But three.js examples like threejs.org/examples/#games_fps might be helpful, feel free to open a new question if you get stuck with a particular issue.

Comment: Am just asking if there is a way to check collisions between a box and a custom gltf model.

Comment: Please see the example linked in my comment, and particularly the use of an octree, if you're not sure where to start. The button in the lower right will show you the source code.